# How to handle validation of login data with passport

Tags: node.js, validation, express, passport-local

I am building an API with node/express and choose to handle authentication with passport and JWT.
I use a LocalStrategy when user logs in, then a jwt strategy once he  has a valid token.
I would like to do some validation on username and password, like checking username is an email address, or password is at least n chars, or simply check for not-empty username and/or password.

I tried to implement validation inside LocalStrategy definition, but if one or both username and password are empty LocalStrategy does not run at all.

Where should login data validation be performed?

Comment: Take a look at the starter api I have created: https://github.com/BCooperA/express-authentication-starter-api

Comment: Thank you - I see you do validation before calling passport auth... I'll do the same